# Temporary disable angular translate for testing

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

Do anyone know if it's possible to temporary disable Angular Translate (https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/api) in way which result with displaying exact string that is passed to translate filter/service/directive?

For code like:

- `<a>{{'translation.key' | translate}}</a>`
- `$filter('translation')('translation.key')`

I would like to get `translation.key` as output - so just output the passed key.

Then I will be able to test which strings are subjects of translations by seeing `translation.key` string in rendered page.

Comment: You could just comment out or exclude the js files that contain the translations.

Comment: @piscator Thx, that did the trick.

It would be also nice to do it in less hacky way by configuring $translationProvider so I will keep this question not-answered.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm not able to find a configuration setting for this. A cleaner hack would be to set $translate.use('disable'); Since 'disable' isn't a language key, nothing will be translated.